# Using HTML from Python Code

Tags: python, email

I am trying to mail a HTML code from python. Till 900 characters it is coming fine in mail.
However, with increasing characters it is missing some of the characters.

Example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,logging,sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import shutil,ConfigParser,shlex,subprocess
from mail import sendmail

str="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
str+="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
str+="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
str+="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
str+="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
str+="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
str+="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
str+="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
....
...
...

sendmail(str, 'TEST MAIL')
```

This is sending me the mail of 3014 characters although I have 5100 characters in the original str.

How to overcome the issue.

Thanks,
Debayan

Comment: Some characters? Random characters? You are saying it's HTML - so HTML is corrupted? Incoming message is not readable?

Comment: No. see I am trying to generate a mail from with Job names and timings the html is fine, but the problem is when I am doing it for more that 4 jobs I am not receiving the full mail. Like I wrote earlier, lets say I am trying to print the str till 1000 characters it is getting printed without any issue but after 1000 characters it is not printing some of the last characters. Like in the above example I had 5100 characters but it printed only 3014 characters